# compare two values in sql with eachother

Tags: mysql, sql, t-sql, magento, compare

I have a database of magento with double images, I want to delete those but first i got to detect them with a sql query.

I have tried this code

```
select t1.VALUE from catalog_product_entity_media_gallery t1 
join catalog_product_entity_media_gallery t2 on (t1.value = t2.value)
```

this one:

```
  select * from catalog_product_entity_media_gallery where value=value
```

and this one:

```
select
*
from
(
    select
        value
    from
        catalog_product_entity_media_gallery
    group by
        value
    having count(*) > 1
) as t
inner join catalog_product_entity_media_gallery on (
    catalog_product_entity_media_gallery.value = t.value
)
```

the first gives an error and the second- and third one gives back every product.

[image: this is my small test database]

Comment: What is the schema of the table catalog_product_entity_media_gallery? Is it the last picture?

Comment: Yes it is the last picture

Answer (score 0):

Give this one a try:

```
select
*
from (
    select 
        entity_id,attribute_id,value,
        MIN(value_id) value_id
    from catalog_product_entity_media_gallery
    group by
        entity_id,attribute_id,value
    having COUNT(*) > 1
) A1
inner join catalog_product_entity_media_gallery A2 on
    A1.entity_id = A2.entity_id and
    A1.attribute_id = A2.attribute_id and
    A1.value = A2.value and
    A1.value_id = A2.value_id
```

Comment: it doesnt give back any results

Comment: congrats all the value_id have different values. if not true please supply more sample data.

Comment: this is all the data, i made a test database with only two products, one product with the entity_id:4 and one with 5,
all the images have different value_id's

Comment: so... with that sample data you want to delete row with value_id: 5?

Comment: could you try the second query i supplied

Comment: it gives me this error: FUNCTION ROW_NUMBER does not exist

Comment: What SqlServer version are you running?

Comment: i am using phpmyadmin on a wamp environment

Comment: then you are running MySql and not Microsoft Sql-Server. Wrong tag.

Answer (score 0):

You can just get the min id by value, then except the other records:

```
select
*
from catalog_product_entity_media_gallery t1
where exists
( select * from 
  (select  value, min(value_id) as min_value_id
    from   catalog_product_entity_media_gallery
    group by  value
  ) as t2
  where t1.value=t2.value and t1.value_id=t2.min_value_id
)
```

If you want delete the duplicated rows, change exists to not exists.

```
delete
from catalog_product_entity_media_gallery t1
where not exists
( select * from 
  (select  value, min(value_id) as min_value_id
    from   catalog_product_entity_media_gallery
    group by  value
  ) as t2
  where t1.value=t2.value and t1.value_id=t2.min_value_id
)
```